# How to get last entered value in a Dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

How do I get the last entered value in a Dictionary in Swift? For example how would I get the value "CCC" from below:

```
var dictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()
dictionary.updateValue("AAA", forKey: "111")
dictionary.updateValue("BBB", forKey: "222")
dictionary.updateValue("CCC", forKey: "333")
```

Comment: Dictionaries don't have any order so there's little sense in trying to get the last value. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: if you need to keep an order just use an array, or create a var to store the last key updated

Comment: @rmaddy I am trying to have a String key while also having an index because order does matter

Comment: If order matters then a dictionary is the wrong collection.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you for your advice. What type of collection would you recommend then?

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is generally known as a Ordered Dictionary, i.e. a dictionary that remembers the order that items have been added. A quick Google search turns up a GitHub project that may suit you.

https://github.com/lukaskubanek/OrderedDictionary

With this as the type of your dictionary, you could just use:

```
dictionary.last // returns Optional(("CCC", "333"))
```

The GitHub page has details on how you would go about adding this class to your project.

Answer (score 0):

If your key is sorted you can try:

```
var dictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()
dictionary.updateValue("AAA", forKey: "111")
dictionary.updateValue("BBB", forKey: "222")
dictionary.updateValue("CCC", forKey: "333")

print(dictionary.keys.sorted().last.map({ ($0, dictionary[$0]!) }))
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of dictionaries is they're **NOT** ordered. This is why their lookups are generally so fast is because they partition elements without regard for their order.

If you want items in a particular order, you should use an array. Yes, "sorted dictionaries" exist, but they're really just dictionary-like interfaces on top of arrays. They contain none of the benefits that traditional dictionaries bring.

If you think you need an ordered dictionary, you probably need to consider a new structure for your data.

Answer (score 0):

//If you need to build a query string for http:

```
let httpBody:[String : String] = [
    "Street"   : "1234 W 1st Street",
    "Building" : "Suite 500",
    "City"           : "Los Angeles",
    "State"          : "CA",
    "Zip"       : "92005"
]

var idx = 0
var queryStr = ""
for (k, v) in httpBody {

    if idx == httpBody.count - 1 {
        queryStr += k + "=" + v
    } else {
       queryStr += k + "=" + v + "&"
       idx += 1
    }
}
print(queryStr)

//Example: for some REST API
//let bodyData:Data = queryStr.data(using: .utf8)!
//request.httpBody = bodyData

//Or this option: 

var newStr = ""
for (k, v) in httpBody {
    let index = httpBody.index(httpBody.startIndex, offsetBy: httpBody.count - 1)
    if k == httpBody.keys[index] {
        newStr += k + "=" + v
    } else {
       newStr += k + "=" + v + "&"
    }
}
print( "\n", newStr)
```