# Swift - How to get the lastkey of a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I'm working with a dictionary and I would like to know how to get the last value.

I got the first value by using `myDictionary.keys.first` and I tried to get the last value by doing `myDictionary.keys.last` but it's not working.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The order of dictionaries is unspecified, so even `first` is kind of nonsense and only well defined if the dictionary has 1 key/value pair.

Comment: see this for further understanding : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42804682/5774854

Comment: Thank you guys, I used `sorted()` and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access first of last value of dictionary, because `Dictionary` does not have a specific order, unlike `Array`. Calling `myDictionary.keys` will return an array, but you have no guarantee the order of that array will not change when you add/remove elements from dictionary.

Comment: `myDictionary.keys` returns a (lazy) collection, *not* an array (otherwise you could call `.last` on it).

Answer (score 1):

Index only applies to arrays, where you have an order in it. Say you can add element at the beginning, or to the end of the array, and then get element from a specific index.

Dictionary on another hand, does not have such ordering. It is hashed in a way that make it faster when you are trying to get value for a key. When you add a key value pair, it automatically added to an *imaginary index* that you won't know. So you should not be getting key value pairs from a dictionary by index.